# Variable name has a variable at the end

Tags: javascript, variables

```
if (playerturn == 1) {
     currentpos1 = startpos1 + dicetotal;
     prevpos1 = currentpos1 - dicetotal;
 } else {
     currentpos2 = startpos2 + dicetotal;
     prevpos2 = currentpos2 - dicetotal;
 }
```

I know this is a slight duplicate of other questions, but I still didn't understand the answers. This is for a monopoly board game, which can have upto 6 players. I want to clean up the code, because the only thing that changes is the last part of the variable.

Currentpos(i), Prevpos(i), Startpos(i) are variable names. So how would I concatenate a variable into a variable name?

Comment: shall we inform waddingtons?

Comment: Don't. Use an arrays or objects instead.

Comment: Quentin ok. Perhaps you could show me how I could use arrays or objects instead?

Comment: And no my question is not a duplicate. They are trying to have variable variables. Whereas I am trying to make 6 different variables, but want to automate naming them by adding a variable at the end of their names

Comment: @EltonFrederik — That's what variable variables *are*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object instead of variables.

```
var players = {
      playername : { 
          currpos:'val',
          prevpos:'val',
          startpos:'val',
          ....
      },
      ....

  }
```

Adding new player

```
players['playername1'] = { 
          currpos:'val',
          prevpos:'val',
          startpos:'val',
          ....
      }
```

And usage is `players['playername'].currpos` so in yur case jus
`players['playername'+playerturn].currpos =  players['playername'+playerturn].startpos + dicetotal;`

or array

```
var players = [
    { 
        currpos:'val',
        prevpos:'val',
        startpos:'val',
        ....
    },
    { 
        currpos:'val',
        prevpos:'val',
        startpos:'val',
        ....
    }
];
```

Adding new player:

```
 players.push({ 
        currpos:'val',
        prevpos:'val',
        startpos:'val',
        ....
    });
```

And usage is `players[0].currpos` so in your case `players[playerturn].currpos =  players[playerturn].startpos + dicetotal`

Comment: Thanks nzn. I will play around with it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @EltonFrederik, even though the answer seems correct, you shouldn't mark it as a correct answer until you are absolutely sure of it.

Comment: Yes Anar you are right, I got carried away. But anyway I can confirm now that I got it to work. So all is good.